# Nesting App.post and App.get, good practise or bad idea?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For developping my current application I'm using a some app.post and app.get to CRUD data into my DB.

I would like to konw, since in almost every app.post and app.get I'm requesting things from my DB, if it would be better to encapsulate my get and post inside each other.

This is an empiric example :

```
app.get ("/home"){
res.render("/home")
app.post("/form1"){
db.collection.find(stuf)
res.render("/form1")}
}
```

And so on

The "classic" would be :

```
app.get ("/home"){
res.render("/home")}

app.post("/form1"){
db.collection.find(stuf)
res.render("/form1")
}
```

Comment: I don't see why you would think that's a better way to do it. You'll just end with a lot of `}` in the end for no visible advantage, and I'm not even sure it would work in the first place.

Comment: Well, it's mainly to reduce database access during my creating of data. It's just an idea that occured to me and I just wanted to know if anyone have done it, and if not why it's pointless. I'm just genuinely curious :)